# Link for DataAccessBase

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone please provide me link on Basic of DataAccessBase  class and it's usage?

Comment: Where did you find this class? Is it something you have in your source code? Are you using some 3rd party library? Are you integrating with some system that exposes this class?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking at code generated by VisualStudio:

[Auto-Generating Custom Solutions in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379554(VS.80).aspx)